# Constructing character table given group size, conjugacy class size and 3 characters

Tags: representation-theory, characters

I am working through some notes on representation theory, and in the questions I have come across this question:

A group of order $168$ has $6$ conjugacy classes of sizes $1, 21, 42, 56, 24, 24$. Three representations of this group are known, with their character given as:

$A: 14, 2, 0, -1, 0, 0 $

$B: 15, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1 $

$C: 16, 0, 0, -2, 2, 2 $

(So on the class of size 1, $Tr(A(x)) = 14$, on the class of size 21, $Tr(A(x)) = 2$ and so on)

There is also a hint that you can assume that $\sqrt{7}$ is not in $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta)$ where $\zeta$ is a seventh root of unity

I first computed the inner products of each representation with itself and with each other:

$\langle A, B\rangle = 1$, $\langle A, C\rangle = 2$, $\langle C, B\rangle = 2$

$\langle A, A\rangle = 2$, $\langle B, B\rangle = 2$, $\langle C, C\rangle = 4$

So $A, B$ are each the sum of two irreducible characters, and $C$ is either twice an irreducible character or the sum of $4$ irreducible characters, but if it were the sum of $4$ irreducible characters, $C - B$ would be a degree $1$ character, and therefore irreducible, but also the sum of $2$ irreducible characters, contradiction, so $C = 2\chi_1$, and we have our first irreducible character.

The inner products with $A, B$ show that $\chi_1$ is one of the two characters that sum with them, so $\chi_2 = A - \chi_1$ and $\chi_3 = B - \chi_1$ are irreducible characters, so including the trivial character, we have 4 out of 6 characters:

$\chi_0: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1$

$\chi_1: 8, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1$

$\chi_2: 6, 2, 0, 0, -1, -1$

$\chi_3: 7, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0$

Now as $168 = \sum_0^5 \chi_i(1)^2$, we have that the remaining representations are both degree $3$.

I know that we can get these by column and row orthogonality and solving the ridiculous amount of simultaneous equations that we get, and using products of characters I have that:

$\chi_4 + \chi_5: 6, -2, 2, 0, -1, -1$

But is there a quicker way to get them?

Comment: The last two classes have centralizer of order $7$, and since all subgroups of order $7$ are conjugate (Sylow...) these elements must be labelled by $x$ and $x^{-1}$. Thus the last two values are complex conjugates, and the two degree $3$ characters are conjugate. Since all other classes are real, this means $\chi_4(g)=\chi_5(g)$ for all other $g$, making the column orthogonality much easier.

Comment: Another thing to try is to generate a high-dimensional character and hope it contains your missing characters. For example, $\chi_1^2 : 64, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1$ is the character of $\rho_1 \otimes \rho_1$, and you just need to calculate inner products to verify that it contains $\chi_0 + 3\chi_1 + 2\chi_2 + 3\chi_3$ and what remains is your $\chi_4 + \chi_5$.

Comment: Oh and a more general fact that you'll get to see: for any finite group $G$, the [regular representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_representation) has character $\chi_G : |G|, 0, 0, ..., 0$, and it contains all irreducible characters, with the number of copies of $\chi_i$ in $\chi_G$ being equal to $\chi_i(1)$.